# Vertical line in email signature has a lip in Chrome

Tags: html, email

As seen in the green circle. Any ideas as to why this would be happening?

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<table style="margin-top:40px;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:30px;width:95%" border="0">
 <tr height="45">
  <td width="105">
   <span style="font-family:'Calibri',helvetica,San-Serif;font-size:15px;color:#333;line-height:15px"><b style="font-weight: bold;">CONCUR </b><b style="color:#DE2C38; font-weight:normal;">LABS</b>
  </td>
  <td>
  <div style="height:45px; width:1px; background:#888; margin-right: 2px;"> </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <span style="font-family:'Calibri',helvetica,San-Serif;font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:15px"><b style="font-weight: bold;">Alicia</b>, Sr User Experience Designer<br />
   <span style="font-family:'Calibri',helvetica,San-Serif;font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:22px"><a href="tel:123.456.7891" title:"Call me" style="color:#777">123.456.7891</a></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b style="color:E9212D;">|</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:alicia@website.com" title="email me" style="color:#777">alicia@website.com</a></span>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks okay on Opera, and also I don't see any problem with code too.

Comment: Is there any other code than this ? maybe the problem is outside

Answer (score 0):

Your html have some messy tags, the first `<span>` not being properly closed in particular.

```
<table style="margin-top:40px;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:30px;width:95%" border="0">
    <tr height="45">
        <td width="105">
            <span style="font-family:'Calibri',helvetica,San-Serif;font-size:15px;color:#333;line-height:15px"><b style="font-weight: bold;">CONCUR </b><b style="color:#DE2C38; font-weight:normal;">LABS</b></span>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div style="height:45px; width:1px; background:#888; margin-right: 2px;"> </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="font-family:'Calibri',helvetica,San-Serif;font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:15px"><b style="font-weight: bold;">Alicia</b>, Sr User Experience Designer<br />
            <span style="font-family:'Calibri',helvetica,San-Serif;font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:22px"><a href="tel:123.456.7891" title="Call me" style="color:#777">123.456.7891</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b style="color:E9212D;">|</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:alicia@website.com" title="email me" style="color:#777">alicia@website.com</a></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There was an un-opened `</b>` tag and a horrible `title:"Call me"` I corrected too. :p